# bash file completion without specifying "./"

Tags: linux, bash, centos, autocomplete

I am using a minimal install of CentOS 8.

If I have a folder called "some_folder" in my home folder, on the command line I can do:

```
some <now hit tab, and bash completion resolves to "some_folder">
```

However, if I have a file called "my_file" in my home folder, at the prompt, I type:

```
my_ <now hit tab, and NOTHING happens, bash completion does not work>
```

Apparently, I have to go back and type `./my_` before hitting tab(!?). Do you know how I can get CentOS to tab complete for files in the same way that it does for folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current directory isn't (or shouldn't be) in your `$PATH`, so it's not a valid location in which to find executables. In this example, `my_` is the prefix to a command, and so will not be found in your current directory:

```
my_<tab>
```

In this example, the `my_` is an ordinary file and can be found by tab completion:

```
cat my_<tab>
```

Comment: My current directory is not in my `$PATH`. Are you saying that it will only tab complete if `my_file` is an executable? 

It does autocomplete after `cat` as you suggest but I'm still confused.

ok, next test, I set `chmod 777 my_file` and try to do `my_` and it still won't complete.

Are you saying that it will only autocomplete from locations that are on the path, and will not autocomplete an executable file, even if that is in my `pwd`? Is that standard behaviour on most distros?

Comment: Yes exactly that, it must be executable *and* in `$PATH`.  This behaviour is from the shell rather than the distro (I would expect the vast majority of shells to behave in the same manner).

Comment: I've been doing lots of work on PowerShell for the last few years (not been touching Linux servers much) and PowerShell allows you to tab a file in that in way (which makes sense as if you tab complete a `.txt` file for example, then hit `Enter` it will open that file with an associated app. As you say, I guess it's just particular to the philosophy of Linux shells that I forgot.

Comment: I just installed `pwsh` on CentOS there and confirmed that the behaviour for `pwsh` on Linux is the same as Windows. i.e. if I type in `my_` (without a `./`) and then hit `TAB` it adds the `./` to resolve the full filename as `./my_file`.

Comment: Windows and PowerShell a different beast.  Windows will attempt to "run" any given file.  The responses will range from execution for things like `.cmd` and `.exe` (etc), to opening in the associated program for registered extensions, and just telling you there's nothing associated for everything else.  Sounds like `pwsh` is bringing some Windows idioms along with it for least surprise (but also accommodating other shell norms by prefixing `./` for you).

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a command preceding `my_` then the shell will only complete with the names of local directories, or executable files that are in the `PATH`.  By default the current directory is not in the `PATH` for reasons of best practice.

If you were to do `ls my_<TAB>` then it should complete for you.

Answer (score -1):

One way could be by adding the current directory to your PATH environment variable in your profile, but in this way it could be dangerous since you can execute scripts
without doing it on purpose (without ./) :

```
export PATH="$PATH:."
```

Comment: Whilst this would "solve" the problem as described, it's generally not a good idea as you might end up doing something like running a `PWD` executable that name clashes with a system binary.  The impact of this could run the gamut from "surprise", "confusion" and "inconvenience" at the low end all the way to "dangerous" and "potentially compromising security" at the high end.

Comment: @bxm: It is adding the current directory at the end of the search path, so system will take priority. It would still help running something that should not be, though. I agree it would be a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed that adding it at the end is of lower risk, but `$PATH` is not immutable. All it takes is some other sourced script to append to `$PATH` later and you’re back into realms of unintended consequences.